# Getting checkboxes + labels aligned correctly in form

Tags: css

I have created a jsfiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/CpWTp/5/

As you can tell the checkboxes are on the wrong side (although I could live with the way they are now). I also want the label and checkbox to lineup so it looks uniform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/CpWTp/19/)

Answer (score 0):

This does it:

http://jsfiddle.net/CpWTp/22/

And `.field_row` is in the right place.